# Azure VM configuration with 2 public static IP

Tags: azure

I have broken my head, trying to fulfill following configuration:
2 Azure VMs behind load balancer, with static public IP assigned to load balancer + one of those VMs shall have it's own static public IP.

I was trying to fulfill this both with portal and Azure Resource Manager temaplates - but it is not working.
When in portal I try to assign instance IP address - it is not static, and will change each time VM is shutdown.

When in Azure Resource Manager I try to provision a VM via template in which 3 NICs are created for 2 VMs - I could not attach 3rd NIC to one of VMs with a mystical error, which I could not track in logs :(

I am compeletely lost in this subject :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reserve the PIP (Instance Level IP) address, only the VIP (Public Virtual IP). You also can only have 1 reserved VIP per cloud service no matter how many NICs you have. To reserve a VIP you can either use Powershell or the Preview Portal that way they won't change next time you restart or shutdown.

**Reserved IP Overview**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

**Update:**

You can now have multiple VIPs per cloud service (Only VMs, not available for roles)

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/multiple-vips-per-cloud-service/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/

Comment: So, to fulfill my scenario (I need one machine to run particuar, unshareable workload) - I need to deploy 3 VMs: 2 are serving shareable workloads behind loadbalancer, while one are delivering unshareable workload.
So, I will end up with 2 VIP.
Is this asumption correct? Or there is another, better way?

Comment: Basically you'd want to place VMs which shares the same roles in the same cloud service for load balancing, auto scale, etc. only. Only deploy VMs that are exactly the same in the same cloud service. It's like, if I turn off this one i would still have the other one to answer incomming requests but when you have a VM running IIS server and a VM with Sql Server in the same cloud service, that doesn't make much sense as they will share resources that they weren't suppose to share like the VIP.

Comment: Also, make sure to always have more than one VM for redundancy if possible. As an example, the cost to have 2x A2 VMs = 1 A3. So why not have 2x A2 instead of just 1 A3 VM? Most applications will also perform better if you split the load between machines instead of funneling the requests to just one even if they have fewer resources.